# Possible to execute SQL from Perl through PHP in order to provide thorough performance stats?

Tags: php, mysql, perl, dbi, newrelic

I have a rather obscure question, which I'll probably get shot down for asking, but here goes.

I have just implemented New Relic web application monitoring for my site which is made up of roughly 70% legacy Perl code and 30% newer PHP code. New Relic gives some really nice information for slow SQL which I'd like to be able to analyse.

The problem is that New Relic does not provide Perl support, so I can only see 30% of my applications query statistics.

As a workaround, I had a pretty insane idea whereby I could potentially prepare my SQL in Perl as normal, then exec/shell out to a PHP script which executes the SQL using its built-in interface, then return the results back to perl somehow. (I have no idea if this is even possible). This way, I'd be able to see the other 70% of SQL statistics that I am currently unable to see.

I've heard about the [PECL Perl extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/perl) but have yet to look into it in any detail. Does anyone know if/how I could accomplish something like this? Or suggest any alternative Perl/SQL monitoring tools I could use alongside new relic?

Regards,
**ns**

Comment: You don't say which database engine you're using, but a non-zero number of the major database engines include logging/alerting of slow queries in one form or another.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you rewrite your app, the amount of work to "shell out" to PHP, and the commensurate run-time penalty you'll pay as a result make me think you ought to entertain a rewrite, or reevaluate your need to get this data from New Relic instead of some other way.

Comment: Can you not get what you want from [DBI::Profile](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI::Profile)'s rich statistics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your pointers.

I was blue-sky thinking when I asked this question. I have since realised that performance is likely to take a big hit, and it is an ugly solution to implement. I will instead try working with alternative tools alongside new relic.

Cheers! ns